# Haystack Search with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-haystack

I have managed to get the haystack search working, and working for the most part how I'd like it to, the only thing that bothers me is that when I go to the search page there is a "SearchIn" option and there is a checkbox with the label "documents" and no matter if it is checked or not, the results yield the same,  I was wondering if anyone knows how to remove this, I know this is probably an easy fix, but I can't seem to figure it out.  If you have any other additional questions or concerns feel free to leave a comment.  Thank you in advance.

models.py:

```
class Course(models.Model):

    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

     def __unicode__(self):

       return self.subject

class Document(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    subject_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=999,default=False)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    description = models.TextField(default=None)
    pub_date = models.DateField(default = datetime.date.today())

    def __unicode__(self):

      return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):

      return "/main/get/%i/" % self.id
```

---

search_indexes.py :

---

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from notes_app.models import Document, Course

class DocumentIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):

  text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
  course = indexes.CharField(model_attr="course")
  subject_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr="subject_name")
  subject_number = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr="subject_number")
  description = indexes.CharField(model_attr="description")
  title = indexes.CharField(model_attr="title")
  pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr="pub_date")


  def get_model(self):

    return Document

  def index_queryset(self, using=None):

    #Used when entire index for model is updated.
    return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

---

document_text.txt :

---

```
{{ object.course }}
{{ object.subject_name }}
{{ object.subject_number }}
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.description }}
{{ object.pub_date }}
{{ object.body }}
```

---

search.html :

---

```
<form method="get" action=".">
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        {% if query %}
            <h3>Results</h3>
            <table cellspacing="30">
              <tr>
                 <td>Course</td>
                 <td>Subject Name</td>
                 <td>Subject Number</td>
                 <td>Title</td>
                 <td>Description</td>
                 <td>Date Uploaded</td>
              </tr>
            {% for result in page.object_list %}


              <tr>
                <td align = "center"><a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{    result.object.course }}</a></td>
                <td align = "center"><a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.subject_name }}</a></td>
                <td align = "center"><a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.subject_number }}</a></td>
                <td align = "center"><a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.title }}</a></td>
                <td align = "center"><a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.description }}</a></td>
                <td align = "center"><a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.pub_date }}</a></td>
              </tr>

            {% empty %}
                <p>No results found.</p>
            {% endfor %}
          </table>
          </form>
```

Comment: Which form are you using?

Comment: Thats one thing im not sure on I think it is using a default form that is built in with haystack.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by replacing the current form with the following:

```
<form method="get" action="/search/">
      <input type="text" name="q">
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    # Some Code
</form>
```